# Gulp minify and move files with same folder structure

Tags: gulp

I have a folder structure like this:

```
.
├── dist/
└── src/
    ├── index.php
    └── projects/
        ├── some-project/
        │   ├── main.css
        │   ├── main.js
        │   └── index.html
        └── N'th project/ ...
```

I need to minify and move every project inside src/ to dist/ without breaking folder structure. Should look like this:

```
.
├── dist/
│   ├── index.php
│   └── projects/
│       ├── some-project/
│       │   ├── main.css(minified)
│       │   ├── main.js(minified)
│       │   └── index.html
│       └── N'th project/ (also minified) ...
└── src/
    ├── index.php
    └── projects/
        ├── some-project/
        │   ├── main.css
        │   ├── main.js
        │   └── index.html
        └── N'th project/ ...
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with something like this. If any one want to use:

```
.pipe(gulp.dest(function(file){
            let splittedUrl = file.history[0].split("\\");
            let projectName = splittedUrl.slice(splittedUrl.indexOf("projects"),-1);
            //console.log(projectName.join("/"));
            return "dist/" + projectName.join("/");
        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task("projectTest", () => {

  return gulp.src("./src/projects/**/*.css")
    // minify pipe, etc.
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/projects'))
});
```

From https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#glob-base:

> A glob base - sometimes called glob parent - is the path segment
>   before any special characters in a glob string. As such, the glob base
>   of `/src/js/**.js` is `/src/js/`. All paths that match the glob are
>   guaranteed to share the glob base - that path segment can't be
>   variable.
>
> Vinyl instances generated by `src()` are constructed with the glob base
>   set as their `base` property. When written to the file system with
>   `dest()`, the `base` will be removed from the output path to preserve
>   directory structures.

That is a little confusing as written.  In my code the part before the globstar `**` is the `base`.  So `./src/projects/` is the base.  And the directory structure under the `base` is always preserved - but that wouldn't include `projects` (because that is part of the `base` and will be removed automatically in `gulp.dest`).

In the `dest` pipe, the directory structures (project1, project2, etc.) are still there but would be sent to your `dest` folder without the `base` path at the beginning.  So you will need to add whatever part of that `base` path back into your `dest` folder if you want it.

So `gulp.dest('dist/projects')` to get the preserved folder structure put back under `projects` as you want.

---

So if what I said is true, this alternative should work as well:

```
gulp.task("projectTest", () => {

  // return gulp.src("./src/projects/**/*.css")

  return gulp.src("./src/**/*.css")

    // .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/projects'))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});
```

Now the directory structure under `src` is preserved (becasue `src` is the `base`).  So you get the same result just sending all that to `dist`.

You can decide which form you prefer, I think the first version is a little clearer.  And if there are files under `src` that you do not want captured by the `gulp.src` glob.